# What is the fictional date range for "The Children of Night" by Frederik Pohl, (1964)?

Tags: short-stories

"The Children of Night" by Frederik Pohl was first published in the October 1964 issue of *Galaxy Magazine*, and has been reprinted a number of times.

[https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57220[1]](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57220%5B1%5D)

I suppose that many  users of this site should have access to books where it is reprinted.

For a long time I have occasionally wondered whether its fictional date was aleady in the past or still in the future.

[Oops.  I remembered the location wrong.  It is actually Belport, state unnamed. So the location is not a community named Port Washington, probably either the city of Port Washington, NY; Port Washington, Ohio; the city of Port Washington, Wisconsin; or the town of Port Washington, Wisconsin.]

The titular children lived in the colony on Mars until capured by Arcturians.  After probably years of Arcturian captivity, though probably not many years considering the young ages of the children, they are being cared for in the hospital at Belport, except that some of the healthier ones have been adopted by members of the local community.

The narrator, "Gunner", works for a public relations firm hired by the Arcturian government, and is in Port Washington to influence the local election over granting the Arcturians an armistice monitoring station at Belport, with the possibility that the war might resume if things go wrong.

One of the first date clues is that "Gunner" reminds a fellow employee how that employee Bungled an election back in the 1980s. Assuming they were both at least 18 at the time, sometime during the 1980s, they would have been born before or during between the period 1962 to 1971.  Assuming that they are both less than 65 in the story, the latest it could possibly be would be 2027 to 2036.

The principal opponent of allowing the Arcturian base should be aged about 30 to 60 at the time.  A bit of dirt to use against him was that he was dishonorably discharged from the army.  But that does not seem so bad since he was a young draftee stationed on the Moon during a meteor shower when many soldiers paniced and were dishonorably discharged.  If a young draftee was 18 to 25, and is now 30 to 60, the story should be 5 to 42 years later.  I forget when the incident happened, but if it was during the 1970s or 1980s the story should happen sometime between 1975 and 2031.

Learning about that incident makes "Gunner" think about when he was a 19-year-old soldier stationed on the Moon, guarding it against alien invaders, which they considered a Joke, since that was before the Arcturian War began.  I don't remember for sure, but I think that was dated to the 1970s.  If it was in the 1970s, and if "Gunner" is less than 65, that should date "The Children of Night" to before or during the period of 2016 to 2025.

And I think that all three of those incidents were dated to specific years in the story, though I don't remember which years.

So if anyone has access to a copy of "The Children of Night" they could look up the years of those incidents, and possibly find other clues to the possible date range which I forget at the moment.

[Added June 3 to 4, 2021. David Ws answer shows that "The Children of Night" should happen about 2022.  in my own answer I go a step further and calculate that "The Children of Night" should happen during Sunday, October 30 and MOnday, October 31, in 2022.  It is nice to know whether its fictional date is already in the past or still in the future.]

Comment: Most people will have access to the images of that old *Galaxy* at the Internet Archive. https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v23n01_1964-10/page/n158/mode/1up

Answer (score 3):

**"Gunner" reminds a fellow employee how that employee messed up an election back in the 1980s.**

> "We met before," I told Haber. "In **1988**, when you were running the Des Moines office."
>
> He beamed and held out his hand. "Why, darn it, so we did! I remember now, Odin."
>
> "I don't like to be called Odin."
>
> "No? All right. Mr. Gunnarsen — "
>
> "Not 'Mr. Gunnarsen', either. Just 'Gunner.'"
>
> "That's right, Gunner; I'd almost forgotten."
>
> I said, "No, you hadn't forgotten. You never knew my name in Des Moines. You didn't even know I was alive, because you were too busy losing the state for our client. I pulled you out of that one, just like I'm going to pull you out now."

**A bit of dirt to use against him was that he was dishonorably discharged from the army. But that does not seem so bad since he was a young draftee stationed on the Moon during a meteor shower when many soldiers panicked and were dishonorably discharged.**

> "Well, it's not on the fax, but I know why he got his DD. 'Desertion of hazardous duty.' On the Moon, in the U.N. Space Force. The year was **1998**."
>
> I nodded, because I understood what she was talking about. Connick wasn't the only one. Half the Space Force had cracked up that year. November. A heavy Leonid strike of meteorites and a solar flare at the same time.

Connick is 41 now, so if he was 17 in 1998 that would put the year at approximately **2022**:

> I turned to Candace, who said promptly, "**Forty-one years old**, Methodist, married, three kids of his own plus one of the casualties, ran for State Senate last year and lost, but he carried Belport, running opposed to the referendum this year, very big in Junior Chamber of Commerce and V.F.W.— "

And the source of him being 17:

> I didn't look back, but kept my eyes on Connick. He squinted his eyes, put his hands in his pockets and said, with considerable self-restraint, "You know I was only **seventeen years old** when that happened."

Answer (score 0):

David W"s answer gives most of the data needed, But he doesn't do all the calculations.

Connick was 17 years old when the Leonid meteors struck in 1998.  Earth (and the Moon) should have been struck by the Leonid meteor shower on November 16 and 17, 1998.

And the meteor stream was especially thick and spectacular in 1998, which no doubt is why Pohl selected the year 1998.  The Leonid meteror shower is at its most spectacular every 33 years, and in 1964 it was easy to calculate that 1998 would be the next most spectacular meteor shower (and thus the most dangerous to people in spacesuits on the Moon) after the one in 1965 which would be too early for the story.

So Connick should have been born sometime between November 17, 1980 and November 16, 1981.  Thus Connick would have turned 41 sometime between November 17, 2021 and November 16, 2022, and should have turned 42 sometime between November 17, 2022, and November 16, 2023.

Presidential elections are held on the first Tuesday following the first Monday in November every four years, and federal elections for the Senate and House of Representatives are held on the first Tuesday after the first Monday in November every two years.  2020 was a presidential election year, and 2022 will have federal elections for the Senate and House.

So if the local election is held on the first Tuesday after the first Monday in November, to coincide with the federal elections, the year must be 2022.  That would mean that the Arcturian War, which lasted 11 years, began in 2011.  Since the first Tuesday following the first Monday in November 2022 will be November 8, the election will probably be on November 8, 2022.

Since user14111's comment led me to this online image of the story in the October 1964 issue of *Galaxy* it may be possible to figure out how many days the story lasts.

[https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v23n01_1964-10/page/n158/mode/1up[1]](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v23n01_1964-10/page/n158/mode/1up%5B1%5D)

On the first day "Gunner" is in Belport it is said:

> "The referendum on granting rezoning privaleges to our client was going to a vote in less than two weeks."

So the day should be sometime between Wednesday, October 26 and Monday, October 31, 2022.  Connick's kids wear snowsuits that night, so it isn't summertime. The next day, "Gunner" says:

> I think you're trying to tell me something, and it isn't all about Preposition Four on the ballot next week.

So the second day should be during the week of Sunday, October 30 to Saturday, November 3, in 2022.

Later that day someone says:

> Nuts! i always watch *Dr. Zhivago* on Monday nights, and it's on in five minutes and_____

So the second day should be Monday, October 31, 2022.

And it looks ilke the quarter moon that "Gunner" observed on the first day in Belport would be rather close to the phase on Sunday, October 3, 2022.

I tried figuring out the date of "The Children of Night" sometime ago, but I don't think that I noticed all the data I needed to make such exact calculations. From time to time over the decades I have wondered whether the fictional date of "The Children of Night" was already in the past or still in the future.

PS  "gunner" mentions *Romper Room*, a tv program for preschool kids which was broadcast from 1953 to 1994.  Since 'Gunner" probably wached *Romper Room* as a kid, he was probably born about 1960 - Pohl had no way of guessing in 1964 how long *Romper Room* would be on the air.